# uncaught (in promise) error bad request react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I have a react app running on the client side which makes calls to a rest API with superagent.

For Error handling, I wanted to add a componentDidCatch().

The Problem is, that the Errorhandler gets the Error submitted but only as a promise.

```
async function makeApiCall(params) {
    return await request
         .post(`${API_ROOT}/getStuff`)
         .send(params)
         .then((res) => {
             return res.body
         })
         .catch((err) => {
              throw err;
         }
```

This part so far works good and does what it is supposed to except for the thrown err to be a promise.

The errorhandler:

```
componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    this.setState({
        hasError: true,
        error: error
    });
}
```

My question is now what to do to make the error in the componentDidCatch function to not be a promise anymore.

Comment: Note that `.catch((err) => { throw err; })` is a no-op. Just remove it.

Comment: Similarly, there's no need for `makeApiCall` to be an `async` function if that's all it does; it just adds overhead. Instead, make it a normal function and just `return request.post(...)`, since `request.post` returns a promise already.

Comment: Are you saying that `componentDidCatch` **is** getting called, but that `error` is a promise? Or that `componentDidCatch` isn't getting called at all?

Comment: Just did some testing and it seems componentDidCatch doesn't get called at all